# How to retrieve TTL value from received TCP packet?

Tags: sockets, tcp

Among the socket options, there is IP_RECVTTL, but this only works with RAW sockets or DGRAM.
How can I get TTL while using TCP socket?

Comment: You can't. What good would it do you?

Comment: The TTL from what? A socket has no TTL, packets have. But TCP does not work on the ideas of packets, i.e. a single `recv` can include data from multiple packets with different TTL.

Comment: I want to know the number of hops the received packet has gone through. There is never any way in TCP?